# Function in select statement makes my query run very slowly

Tags: sql-server, function

I have this query in a stored procedure:

```
SELECT      
    *,
     ISNULL(dbo.ReturnShortageByItemCodeLinePackage(LineId, TestPackageId, MaterialDescriptionId), 0) AS Shortage 
FROM
    dbo.ViewMTO
```

I am using a function inside the query to calculate an integer value as you can see here :

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ReturnShortageByItemCodeLinePackage]
     (@lineId int,@testpackId int, @MaterialDescriptionId int)
RETURNS float
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @shortageQuantity float
    DECLARE @MIVQuantity float
    DECLARE @totalQuantity float
    DECLARE @spoolQuantity float
    DECLARE @ExistInSiteQuantity float
    DECLARE @BeforeDoneQuantity float

    SELECT  
        @totalQuantity = Quantity,
        @spoolQuantity = QuantitySpool,
        @ExistInSiteQuantity = QuantityExistInSite,
        @BeforeDoneQuantity = QuantityBeforeDone
    FROM 
        [SPMS2].[dbo].Materials 
    WHERE
        LineId = @lineId 
        AND TestPackageId = @testpackId  
        AND MaterialDescriptionId = @MaterialDescriptionId

    SELECT
        @MIVQuantity = SUM(QuantityDeliver) 
    FROM
        MaterialIssueVoucherDetails miv
    JOIN
        MaterialRequestContractorDetails mrc ON miv.MaterialRequestContractorDetailId = mrc.Id
    WHERE
        TestPackageId = @testpackId 
        AND LineId = @lineId 
        AND miv.MaterialDescriptionId = @MaterialDescriptionId

    IF @MIVQuantity IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @MIVQuantity = 0    
    END

    SET @shortageQuantity = @totalQuantity - (@BeforeDoneQuantity + @ExistInSiteQuantity + @spoolQuantity + @MIVQuantity)

    RETURN round(@shortageQuantity, 3)
END
```

My query is executed in 3 minutes, it is catastrophic for my users! Is there any better solution?

Comment: Is ViewMTO a view?

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend three things:

A. The following line..

```
SELECT @totalQuantity= ... 
FROM [SPMS2].[dbo].Materials
```

Is this accessing a different database via a Linked Server connection ?  How fast is this connection ?

B.  Your SP contains *two* SELECT statements.  Which of them is the bottleneck ?
  You can add some PRINT statements to show when each is started:

```
PRINT convert(nvarchar, GetDate(), 108) + ' This is the time !'
```

C.  Try running the SQL show on my webpage below, which will highlight missing Indexes.

[Find missing indexes](http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/SQLServer/FindingMissingIndexes.htm)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay...  that answered 1 of my 3 suggestions...  And the other 2 ...?

Answer (score 0):

Convert your Scaler function to Table-Valued function, and then place the function in FROM clause for LEFT JOIN. Do check execution plans to find any warning.

[Testing performance of Scalar vs Table-valued functions in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447346/testing-performance-of-scalar-vs-table-valued-functions-in-sql-server)